# How to replace specific strings between <> using regex

Tags: regex

Can anyone tell me how to do the following task using regex?

replace all the `ABC` with `DEF` only when `ABC` is inside both `<>` and `""`

original string:

```
<tagA nameABC1="attr1ABCx xyzABC" name2="attABCa"> outside"ABC"xyz</tagA>

<tagB nameABC2="attr2ABCx cccABC" name3="testABCb"> outside_"ABC"</tagB>
```

desired string after replacing:

```
<tagA nameABC1="attr1DEFx xyzDEF" name2="attDEFa"> outside"ABC"xyz</tagA>

<tagB nameABC2="attr2DEFx cccDEF" name3="testDEFb"> outside_"ABC"</tagB>
```

Edited:
Thank you guys.
I've decided to use HTML parser library jsoup to handle all html text properly.

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Use an HTML parser so you can properly process all *attributes* (because that seems to be what you really want to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming well formed input (no dangling quotes or brackets):

```
Search: ABC(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*"[^"]*$)(?=[^<>]*>)
Replace: DEF
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/1urxPO4Bo4cTlD).

This works by applying two look aheads:

- the first look ahead `(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*"[^"]*$)` requires there to be an odd number of quote characters in the remaining input, which in turn means the match is inside quotes
- the other look ahead `(?=[^<>]*>)` requires the next angle bracket to be a closing bracket, which in turn means the match is inside an angle bracket pair

This is not bullet proof, for example it doesn't cater for closing angle brackets being inside quotes, but even this could be handled with an even more complicated look ahead that applied similar logic from the first look ahead when matching angle brackets... an excerise left for the reader.

Comment: Thanks. Tried your answer on regex101 site, but got wrong match.

Comment: @Peter OK got it. See edited answer (interesting situation btw!)

Comment: Thank you. However your solution failed when outside strings only have one quotation eg: <tagA nameABC1="attr1ABCx xyzABC" name2="attABCa" > outsideABCx"yz</tagA>

Comment: @peter yes, exactly. As per the opening sentence of my answer, this regex won’t handle malformed input. Nevertheless, this answers the question as you asked it and using the examples you posted.

Comment: Sorry,my bad. Your answer did solve my original question.  Thanks a lot. I've decidede to use HTML parser library jsoup to handle all html text properly.